# docker issue devmapper: Unknown device

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2

my docker build was running properly but now I am facing following error. This issues is for any docker file I run now. I have tried stopping n staring docker it didn't helped.

error :

```
root@ip-172-31-22-20:~/docker/edr# docker build  -t lbx_fromdockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/11 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> 23fc0425aba8
Step 2/11 : CMD bash
devmapper: Unknown device a437f423d02622c9ae555e5f525edd1b0d954f75821825b8a21e118d96437ab3
```

Docker Info :

```
root@ip-172-31-22-20:~/docker/edr# docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 19
Server Version: 17.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-524309-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74GB
 Backing Filesystem: ext4
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 1.366GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4GB
 Data Space Available: 13.17GB
 Metadata Space Used: 1.536MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.146GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.77 (2012-10-15)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9048e5e50717ea4497b757314bad98ea3763c145
runc version: 9c2d8d184e5da67c95d601382adf14862e4f2228
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-116-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.797GiB
Name: ip-172-31-22-20
ID: A5XJ:ZS2M:ILXW:XMJI:RR4C:JLPT:WS5K:WG2I:XJ3N:ZF25:6E5E:N5KH
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: ashishkarpe
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
         Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

ps : this is my poc box and not production one. I am using AWS ec2 Ubuntu instance

```
# uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-22-20 3.13.0-116-generic #163-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:13:22 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: this might be useful root@ip-172-31-22-20:/var/lib/docker# du -sh *
44K     containers
1.3G    devicemapper
6.3M    graph
6.6M    image
16K     linkgraph.db
72K     network
20K     plugins
4.0K    repositories-devicemapper
4.0K    swarm
4.0K    tmp
4.0K    tmp-old
4.0K    trust
28K     volumes

Comment: root@ip-172-31-22-20:/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper# ls -lthr
total 1.3G
-rw------- 1 root root 100G Jul 19 09:22 data
-rw------- 1 root root 2.0G Jul 19 09:39 metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually need to edit (create) the file /etc/docker/daemon.json to change the driver on systemd systems

Create the file at /etc/docker/daemon.json if it does not exist, and add "storage-driver":"aufs".

```
output : 
root@ip-172-31-22-20:~/docker/edr# docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 3
Server Version: 17.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 8
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9048e5e50717ea4497b757314bad98ea3763c145
runc version: 9c2d8d184e5da67c95d601382adf14862e4f2228
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-116-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.797GiB
Name: ip-172-31-22-20
ID: A5XJ:ZS2M:ILXW:XMJI:RR4C:JLPT:WS5K:WG2I:XJ3N:ZF25:6E5E:N5KH
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: ashishkarpe
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe change Storage Driver from devicemapper to aufs3？
[Compatibility Matrix](https://success.docker.com/Policies/Compatibility_Matrix)

Comment: how to change Storage Driver from devicemapper to aufs3 ?

Comment: how to change Storage Driver from devicemapper to aufs3 ? I tried : adding DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=aufs3"
in /etc/default/docker but then # /etc/init.d/docker restart
docker stop/waiting
docker start/running, process 8377
root@ip-172-31-22-20:/var/lib/docker# docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?